# Recording stream locally with VLCKit on MacOS - looking for example

Tags: swift, macos, stream, libvlc, recording

In my MacOS app (Swift) I'm receiving an RTSP stream, which I want to **record** to a local file. I found a few examples using the `.startStreaming()` and `.stopStreaming()` functions from the `VLCStreamSession` object, but these are marked as "***deprecated***" since VLCKit 3.0 version.

I'm looking for an up-to-date **example or hints** how to do that. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I was told that recording is not an official part of the VLCKit lib anymore. The old version was deprecated, but the VLC team plan to integrate this with a complete new solution mid term.